# Membership Manager Prevention of Old Passwords

Tags: passwords

Am I right in presuming that the ASP.Net Membership Manager fails to provide the same facilities as the Acitve Directory in as much as:-

1. preventing old password re-use (say, not in last five passwords)
2. preventing change of password within a certain number of days (to stop recycling to facilitate use of same password)

Cheers

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No the default [ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't do either of those things as default.

You would have to create your own code to manage this yourself.